# What should be the parent of a Maven submodule?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to understand what is the recommended way to have multi module projects with Spring Boot and Maven.

I found a [Spring article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) but I don't understand the given source code.

[This is the source code](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-multi-module/blob/main/complete)

Parent POM: goes as you would expect

```
<?xml version="1.0" ...>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>gs-multi-module</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
      <module>library</module>
      <module>application</module>
  </modules>
```

Child POM (application):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> !!!!!
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>application</name>
```

I tough the parent is supposed to be gs-multi-module. Am I missing something? In general is it supposed the be the parent POM or it can be anything else?

Comment: "*I tough the parent is supposed to be gs-multi-module.*" - In most cases, this is the case, but not necessary. There are - in general - three "forms" of parent we see: the direct parent (i.e. the parent in the directory structure), a sibling in the directory structure (we sometimes see something like a "build-parent" or "test-parent"), or a totally different parent (like shown in the post with the spring-boot-starter-parent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be slightly misunderstanding what the `<parent>` tag refers to and I agree that this can be a bit confusing.

Having a `<parent>` in a Maven project (or module) means that everything from that `<parent>`'s POM is copied to the child POM.
In other words, the `<parent>` in the `pom.xml` is different from the module above your child module (whose POM you called `Parent POM`).

In most cases, you use the top level project as the parent of the Maven modules since that allows you to create common configuration for all your modules.
However, this is not strictly necessary, you can just use any other parent you want (as long as it uses `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. In that case, the author wanted to use `spring-boot-starter-parent` (that simplifies a few things with Spring Boot) which is allowed but it means it would not copy anything from your top level module hence it would be necessary to explicitly specify e.g. a group ID if you don't want to use `org.springframework.boot` for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Often the microservice-architecture rely on independendly releaseable services. So a microservice might be very small and do not contain modules.
2. Sometimes a microservice becomes hugh and maven-module organization become interresting. But this is unpopular because it might be more like an monolith.

For the first point, the usage of spring-boot as a parent is a very recommended and popular approach.

For the second, you might have your very own vanilla parent-pom (packaging:pom) without any further parent-pom (exspecialy no spring-boot-parent). Then you have your submodules as the requirements of the project, and one (or more) submodules have **import** spring-boot-dependencies.

Like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Why are you taliking about microservices? --- "*Often the microservice-architecture rely on independendly releaseable services.*" - "*Sometimes a microservice becomes hugh and maven-module organization become interresting.*" - These two arguments are somewhat contradictory. A multi-module project is typically released "as one" (same version number, for example). This contradcits the indepencence of microservices. I know that we can manage versions separately, but this needs additional configuration and is more akin of a monorepo approach.